# Как сохранить результат команды cmd в переменную?

Tags: java, cmd

Пример:

Команда в консоли `javac -version` Результат: `javac 1.8.0_251`

Как сохранить результат `javac 1.8.0_251` в переменную, к примеру (String ver).

Через гугл нашёл несколько примеров, но все они не сработали. Вот один из них:

```
public void Ver() throws IOException {
    Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd javac -version");
    InputStream in = proc.getInputStream();

    ArrayList ar = new ArrayList();
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
    br.readLine();
    String l;
    while ((l=br.readLine())!=null) {
        ar.add(l);
    }
    System.out.println(l);
}
```

При выполнении просто зависает и всё.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чуть-чуть допилил ваш код. Всё нормально работает. Версия под `linux`:

```
Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("javac --version");
InputStream in = proc.getInputStream();

ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<>();
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

String line;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    arr.add(line);
}

System.out.println(arr); // [javac 14]
```

Comment: Я так и подумал! И в примере написал javac --version, так как все знают что это! А, оказалось не все так просто!!! С cmd я тоже пробовал! Всё просто виснет!

Answer (score 2):

Вот есть интересные [способы](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5711084/java-runtime-getruntime-getting-output-from-executing-a-command-line-program):

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
String[] commands = {"system.exe", "-get t"};
Process proc = rt.exec(commands);

BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));

BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(proc.getErrorStream()));

// Read the output from the command
System.out.println("Here is the standard output of the command:\n");
String s = null;
while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(s);
}

// Read any errors from the attempted command
System.out.println("Here is the standard error of the command (if any):\n");
while ((s = stdError.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(s);
}
```